# How to decode a json dumped by pandas dataframe in swift

Tags: json, swift, dataframe, codable, decodable

I have a json data which is returned by a rest api in the form of

`‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}`
this was generated using `pandas.to_json(orient=‘split’)` in Python

I would like to decode this into a swift object. I tried using decodable but I can't figure out how to dynamically assign the column position to the object

### example data:

```json
{
"columns":
   ["cprcode","iprcode","psqty"],
"index":
   [0,3,4,5,6,11],
"data":
   [
     [123,"abc",123],
     [424, "ads",145],
     [63, "hrw",475],
     [8685, "gds",848],
     [754, "ah",659],
     [374, "rh",597],
   ]
}
```

I would like the output to be in the for of `[Product]`
where

```swift
struct Product{
  let cprcode: Int
  let iprcode: String
  let psqty: Int
}
```

### I have tried

decoding with a custom array class like this, but I'm not sure how to split them into product objects. Note that the columns are dynamic, so hard coding the order of column in data is risky.

```swift
class ProductDF:Codable{
    let columns:[String]
    let index:[Int]
    let data:[[Product]]
}
```

Comment: I think what you want in `struct Product` to have dynamic var names based on the output from API may not be possible. you can try to have a Product as dictionary like a `column:value` to map to dynamic data..If you have troubles achieving this, I can post the sample code.

Comment: a sample will be nice please. I know the var names but can't garuntee the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a custom `init(from:)` where we use nested container to extract Product objects from "data".

Since each sub array under "data" will be a product we change the declaration somewhat

```
struct ProductDF: Codable {
    let columns: [String]
    let index: [Int]
    let data: [Product]
}
```

To simplify the code somewhat we create an enum for the columns

```
enum DataColumn: String {
    case cprcode, iprcode, psqty
}
```

and then the `init(from:)` that we add to `ProductDF`

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    columns = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .columns)
    index = try container.decode([Int].self, forKey: .index)

    var dataContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .data)
    var products = [Product]()
    while !dataContainer.isAtEnd {
        var array = try dataContainer.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
        var cprCode = 0
        var iprCode = ""
        var psQty = 0
        for column in columns {
            switch DataColumn(rawValue: column) {
            case .cprcode:
                cprCode = try array.decode(Int.self)
            case .iprcode:
                iprCode = try array.decode(String.self)
            case .psqty:
                psQty = try array.decode(Int.self)
            case .none:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        let product = Product(cprcode: cprCode, iprcode: iprCode, psqty: psQty)
        products.append(product)
    }
    data = products
}
```

This should do the basic work although I would recommend improving error handling by throwing an error instead of using `fatalError` and also checking that something has been assigned to all 3 variables inside the `while` loop, for instance by making them optional and validating that all are not nil before creating a `Product`